# SMS receiving code works on one device but not on other device (Micromax E4820)

Tags: android, sms

onReceive method doesn't gets called.

I checked the broadcast receiver code for calls and it works fine.
The following code works on my Intex Elyt Dual (7.0) but don't work on other with 6.0.1.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Toast.makeText(context, "on Receive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; ++i) {
                // Convert Object array
                hereComesNewSMS = hereComesNewSMS++ ;
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                // Sender's phone number
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
                // Fetch the text message
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                latestSMSnumber = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                latestSMScontent = str;

            }
            // Display the entire SMS Message
            Log.e("TAG1 number: ", latestSMSnumber);
            Log.e("TAG2 content: ", str);
}
```

Comment: Does the other device possibly have some extra settings or permissions that prevent third-party apps from running in the background, or specifically from receiving SMS, without the user explicitly enabling it? Have a look through the device Settings, and any other standalone, security-related apps that might present.

Comment: I actually read all comments on the similar query and I assure you that WhatsApp, TrueCaller and Mobile Banking apps do receive SMS in the phone for OTP. If it's a matter of more priority to the system app, then how the above said apps Work? Like WhatsApp. Moreover I can assure that TrueCaller doesn't work as Default SMS app even after I set it the default SMS app.
 And about settings: I tried all the app settings and default message app settings and even toggling those settings.

Comment: Well, some manufacturers will have exceptions for big name apps, like WhatsApp, so those will work automatically. However, if your random bank app works without having to somehow enable it, then it possibly doesn't have any further restrictions beyond the usual Android permissions. I really don't understand what you mean by "TrueCaller doesn't work as Default SMS app even after I set it the default SMS app".

Comment: I mean Truecaller doesn't get new received SMS even after I set it default app for SMSes. Any new SMS opens the default Messaging app. I need to open Truecaller if I want to read SMSes in TrueCaller. And the default messaging app handles evey new SMS. 
I checked the behaviour of Messaging by installing new SMS app called "Next SMS". Every time I open the app it ask me to make it the default app for SMS, I did everytime but still it don't become the default SMS app.

Comment: That's really odd. I've never heard of behavior like that. I wouldn't know what to suggest next, without having such a device to observe and test on.

Comment: Leave it Sir Mike M. The device  do have issues in itself. Whenever the other than the system Messaging app is on front, no new SMS is getting detected by neither the app i.e., system SMS app or Next SMS app. I need to send the other app in background or Uninstall it to let new SMSes come. Now, that's not the issue with Android. It's the Manufacturers the unique model issue. Anyways, the code and my app works on all other mobilephones.